# WinMNP config exposing permission issue

Tags: localhost

I installed WinNMP with the typical install. and added two files that I am using to check the installation(among others)

```
C:\Proj\MyRG\public_html\test.htm C:\Proj\MyRG\public_html\application\index.htm

c:\winnmp\conf\nginx.conf file contains: root "C:/Proj/MyRG/public_html/application"

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host file contains both these lines after the install: 127.0.0.1 localhost 127.0.0.1 ProjWinNMPTest.test #WinNMP ProjWinNMPTest.test #WinNMP public_html.test
```

Regardless of how I set WinNMP Manager-->Options(button)-->Projects Dir when I read the test files from a browser

`http://127.0.0.1/public_html/test.htm` correctly reads the simple htlm file.

`http://127.0.0.1/public_html/application/index.html` returns "directory access is forbidden

`http://127.0.0.1/public_html/index.html` returns "404 file not found"

1. How can I set the root file for 127.0.0.1 to point to `C:/Proj/MyRG/public_html/application` instead of `C:/Proj/MyRG/public_html`
2. How can I get permission to access the directory.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer.  And it is unrelated.  The index file itself has the no permission message. This apparently is part of the architecture that I am running on. It was actually displaying exactly correct.